# SQL Server log file issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have my table in SQL Server 2000 with around 500000 records, sometimes my simple select query also taking too much time, I found the reason also why because the log file (`.ldf`) got increased in terms of gb, but I try to shrink my log file using shrink option, and dbcc commands also, but the size is not getting reduced, I am facing this problem once in a day

Please some one suggest me how to shrink log file size, how optimize my database to avoid such a issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting the recovery model to `SIMPLE`?

Comment: The mere size of your log file is certainly not the cause of the performance problems... it might be a symptom, but not the root cause

Comment: I need restore option,that why i made it as full, for example when i insert any data into the table it will very slow, i cant able reduce the size.

Answer (score 1):

The log file is for writes, not SELECTs. A Huge log file can be caused by many things (no log backups, open transactions etc) but it is for writes. Not SELECTs.

Reads won't be affected by the log file size.

So, without adding tables, sample data and the queries we can't help you.

Managing the log file is another question, best asked on [dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I dont know why my db got huge suddenly ,Because of that all my insertion and updates are slow

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be your queries pl. post mode details.

However, if your log is very big, you can truncate it.

Assume you database name is MyDataBase

```
BACKUP LOG  MyDataBase WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY

DBCC SHRINKFILE (MyDataBase_Log, 1)
```